# Javascript Regular Expressions - using * with multiple characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm parsing a string that looks like this:

```
int num 1, num2, num3;

//do some other stuff
```

In betwee those lines, there is a \r\n.  I'm looking to replace \r\n with simply \n, and I got that working fine, howerver, I'd like for it to look for multiple copies of /r/n in a row.  In other words:

/r/n <-- is found

/r/n/r/n <-- this is found also

/r/r/n/n/n <-- this is not found

Here is my current statement:

```
MyData.replace (/(/r|/n)*/g, "someStuff");
```

Do you know any way of how to make the * character apply to multiple characters, so I could look for repetitions of "/r/n"* rather than (/r|/n)* which finds either /r or /n any number of times.

Comment: `(\r\n)*`? ...........

Comment: Erm, `(\r\n)*`?

Comment: Are there \r characters in the data you want to preserve? Did you try `(\r\n)*`?

Comment: @zerkms - I'm a regex lightweight - can you help me understand why `*` instead of `+` ?

Comment: FYI, you need to post a code sample - what have you tried? What's your function look like?  Or at least your regular expression?

Comment: Hey Caleb, I'll edit and add.

Comment: And good point,  I should have used +.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
(\r\n)+
```

The plus matches one or more times.

Or this:

```
/(\r\n)/g
```

The **g** matches all occurrences of the string

Depends on your need or actual code, if you can post it.

Comment: Thanks, this got it.   I wasnt sure if parenthesses could be used for encapsulating multiple characters or just for an OR statement.